# Matricial Equation with both Pointwise and Standard Multiplication

Tags: matrix-equations, convolution, hadamard-product

I am having trouble simplifying an equation that contains both pointwise (Hadamard) and standard matricial multiplication.

Given that $I_{n\times1}$ and $K_{n\times1}$ are real $n\times1$ matrices; $T_{n\times n}$ is a complex $n\times n$ [DFT Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix); and $C_{n\times1}$ is a **real** $n\times1$ matrix representing the [convolution of both arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem) we have:

$$C = \left ( IT \cdot KT \right )T$$

where $\cdot$ denotes pointwise product and $AB$ denotes standard matricial product.

**How can I best simplify this equation?**

It sounds reasonable to me that $C = \left ( I \cdot K \right )T^2$ but I do not know how to prove it.

---

**Edit**:

In fact, $C = \left ( I \cdot K \right )T^2$ cannot be true because the DFT Matrix is involutory, meaning $T^2=I$ (the Identity matrix) and that would mean that convolution in time domain is equal to the pointwise product in the time domain, which is false.

Comment: Assuming $I,K$ have $n$ rows and one column the products $IT$ and $KT$ don' make sense. There is probably a way to define $C$ correctly that should not even give rise to the question how to simplify it. An expression involving $I,K$ and two $T$s is simple in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\op{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
$Let's use a convention where uppercase letters denote matrices and lowercase letters denote column vectors. Then rename the problem variables
$$\eqalign{
\{I,K,C\} \qiq \{a,b,c\} \\
}$$
Define the following diagonal matrices
$$\eqalign{
A &= \Diag{Ta},\quad B = \Diag{Tb},\quad C = \Diag{Tc} \\
}$$
Multiply the given equation by $T$ and use its involutory property
$$\eqalign{
Tc &= T^2\LR{Ta\odot Tb} = \LR{Ta\odot Tb} \\
}$$
For diagonal matrices, an elementwise product is the same as a matrix product. So we can replace the vector equation by an equivalent matrix equation
$$\eqalign{
C &= AB = BA \\
}$$
The latter equality holds since diagonal matrices commute.

The vectors can be easily recovered
$$\eqalign{
a &= T\,\diag{A},\quad b = T\,\diag{B},\quad c = T\,\diag{C} \\
}$$